# Desabilitar parte do formulário pelo JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Eu não tenho muita experiência com JQuery e Ajax.

Estou desenvolvendo um formulário que ao selecionar o Radio Button para enviar informações anônimas, ele deve tornar invisível a parte do formulário que é referente ao endereço.

Estou usando HTML5, CSS3, Bootstrap, PHP.

Comment: Poderia colocar o código já desenvolvido.

Comment: Dê uma conferida no guia [ask]. Se por acaso lê Inglês, [aqui tem um artigo ótimo](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) sobre como melhorar nossa técnica de *escrever perguntas*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá!

Você pode utilizar a função [.hide()](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) juntamente com [.change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/) do jQuery.

```
$("input[name='opcoes']").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() === 'Sim') {
        $("#painelEndereco").fadeIn();
    } else {
        $("#painelEndereco").fadeOut(function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }
});
```

O exemplo completo você pode encontrar aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/vrcca/fC7Yb/

**Edit 1**: Adicionadas as sugestões de [RodrigoBorth](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5818/rodrigoborth).

Abs!

Comment: esse método é funcional, mas poderia ser feito com ajax para substituir o conteúdo por completo sem deixar uma possível "falha" de segurança... recomendo tambem substituir o show e o hide por fadeIn e fadeOut respectivamente, fica mais bonito :D

Comment: Obrigado a todos.
Vou ficar com o exemplo do vrcca.
Muito obrigado.

Comment: Só mais uma coisa.
Onde eu coloco o código JQuery?
Obrigado.

Comment: dentro do $(document).ready. Segue um exemplo da documentação do jQuery: http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/#complete-example

Answer (score 2):

Eu recomendo o uso de `checkbox` para dizer se é anônimo ou não:

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    var $check = $("#checkAnonimo");
    $check.on("change", function () {
        var anonimo = $check.is(":checked");
        anonimo ? $("#camposAnonimo").hide() : $("#camposAnonimo").show();
        $("#camposAnonimo input").prop("disabled", anonimo);
    });
});
```

Note que **além de esconder os inputs relacionados ao endereço, também desativo os mesmos**, pois mesmo ocultos, se você submeter o form, os dados serão enviados caso tenham sido preenchidos previamente.

Html:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <div><label for="textOpiniao">Escreva sua opinião:<br/></label><textarea id="textOpiniao">Sua opinião aqui!</textarea></div>
    <label for="checkAnonimo"><input type="checkbox" id="checkAnonimo"/> Anônimo?</label>
    <div id="camposAnonimo">
        <div><label for="textNome">Nome: <input type="text" name="nome" id="textNome"/></label></div>
        <div><label for="textEndereco">Endereço: <input type="text" name="endereco" id="textEndereco"/></label></div>
    </div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Enviar"/></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Obrigado a todos.
Esta funcionando perfeitamente.